# ImportError: cannot import name 'Annotated' from 'pydantic.typing' when using inflect library in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, importerror

Hello I am using Python 3.8

And I am trying to create a function to sort and print a list in the form of,

> {first_element}, {second_element} and {last_element}

I've used the [inflect](https://pypi.org/project/inflect/) library in Python to do this because it is expected to be used in my assignment.

```py
import inflect
p = inflect.engine()

def sort():
    fruits = ["apple", "banana", "carrot"]
    mylist = p.join(fruits)
    print(mylist)

sort()
```

But when I execute this I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 1, in <module>
    import inflect
  File "/home/username/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/inflect/__init__.py", line 77, in <module>
    from pydantic.typing import Annotated
ImportError: cannot import name 'Annotated' from 'pydantic.typing' (/home/username/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pydantic/typing.py)
```

I tried reinstalling the library called [Pydantic](https://pypi.org/project/pydantic/). But it didn't change anything.

Answer (score 3):

[Pydantic 2.0](https://pypi.org/project/pydantic/2.0/) was released a few hours ago which has introduced breaking changes for `inflect`.

Ideally, inflect should have had an upper max for `pydantic` version in their project. Track the issue on inflect [here](https://github.com/jaraco/inflect/issues/187).

---

Check what version of `pydantic` is installed on your machine. It must be `2.0`. You need to `uninstall` that and `install` the highest `1.xx.x`.

---

I understand this answer will be obsolete once this issue resolves, but here are the only two things to do when such breaking changes are encountered:

1. Check the version you have installed in your machine.
2. Check for issues on the project's GitHub page.

Comment: Explaining how to "check what version of XXX is installed" or "how to uninstall YYY" would be a huge help for many people, I think...